# How to attach interrupts to Arduino UNO timers?

Tags: arduino-uno, interrupt, timers

I understand there are 3 timers on the Arduino UNO.  What specific registers do I need to use to access them?

My goal is to use these timers to poll different sensors I am using with a ms period. Are there any pre-made libraries out there to do this?

Comment: Have you had a chance to look at the datasheet yet?

Comment: The datasheet for the ATMEL SOC, or the Arduino breakout board itself?

Comment: For the MCU (not SoC).

Answer (score 2):

For the UNO, use Timer1.

An example of the way you can use it is as follows:

Download the TimerOne library: https://code.google.com/p/arduino-timerone/downloads/list

```
/*
 *  Timer1 library example
 */

#include "TimerOne.h"

void setup()
{
  pinMode(10, OUTPUT);
  Timer1.initialize(500000);         // initialize timer1, and set a 1/2 second period
  Timer1.pwm(9, 512);                // setup pwm on pin 9, 50% duty cycle
  Timer1.attachInterrupt(callback);  // attaches callback() as a timer overflow interrupt
}

void callback()
{
  digitalWrite(10, digitalRead(10) ^ 1);
}

void loop()
{
  // your program here...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Timer 0 is use'd by the arduino core libraries for functions like millis(). It is best left alone. Leaving timer1 and 3 are available for general use. Both 1 and 3 have well established libraries, for simple implementation, without the need to know the mechanics under the hood, about the registers and such.

You can find links and general explanations at [timer1](http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/Timer1). I always recommend the github versions.

And if you are still wanting to know the details the source is quite readible.

---

Note you don't need 3 timers to read 3 sensors. One timer on a multiple of the the 3, should suffice which can then implement a statemachine to sample at the correct periods.

Comment: I think you mean timer2, not timer3.